# insert into table from a specific .csv file - PHP script

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need help regarding a problem I am facing!
I have a csv file which has individual numbers (20000 numbers) in the 'A' column.So I need to insert them into my table in my database.
I tried this script but no inserts were made into the table..

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['btn_import']))
        {
            $filename = 'test.csv';
            $fp = fopen($filename, "r");
            while (($row = fgetcsv($fp, "20000")) != FALSE)
            {
                $sql = "INSERT INTO `myDB`.`myTable` VALUES ('" . implode("''", $row) . "')";
                if (!$conn->query($sql))
                {
                    echo '<br>Data Insert<br>';

                }
                else
                {
                    echo '<br>No Data Inserted</br>';

                }
            }
            fclose($fp);
        }
        ?>
```

Please comment!
It will be very helpful for me!
Thanks!

Comment: Let's try by turning error_reporting on shall we?

Comment: ...and checking the SQL error message...

Comment: Add this after `echo '<br>No Data Inserted</br>';` so add `echo $conn->error; exit;`

Comment: try this    load data local infile 'pathto/file/location/sss.csv' into table $table_name fields terminated by ',' "." OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\\r\\n' ignore 1 lines

Comment: Could you code what you mean?

Comment: I am rookie so it would be more helpful!

Comment: Your `if` statement doesn't make sense... if `$conn->query($sql)` is `false` echo out "Data Insert"...

Comment: Yes you are right!I change it.My mistake..But I still can't insert into my table?It may be a syntax error in my query?Any ideas?

Comment: try to put column name like this INSERT INTO table_name (column1,)
VALUES (value1);

Answer (score 0):

You can use LOAD DATA INFILE command to import csv file into table.

Check this link [MySQL - LOAD DATA INFILE.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html) for syntax.

Comment: I checked this but I want a php script to figure this out!Thanks a lot!

Comment: you can add load data query in the variable and pass it to mysql query function. 
i.e.
mysqli_query($db, "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'input.txt' INTO TABLE t1");
OR
$conn->query("LOAD DATA STATEMENT");

Comment: Thanks a lot!I am going to check this!

Comment: an alternative for oracle?